# JSON - How to loop through a json object?

Tags: json, object, loops

Im very new to JSON. I already tried the basics of JSON but in the examples Im using it is in array and the key is in string. Mine is quite different, its an object and the key is a number. Example of my JSON object is `var ojbJSON = {55: 3, 23: 2};`. My problems are I cannot get the length for an object because it doesn't have an attribute length and if I do something like `alert(objJSON.55);` to get the value `3` it causes a javascript error. Please don't ask why I'm insisting on this. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: well according to [the JSON spec](http://json.org/) the construct you have isn't even valid JSON: an object (which is what you have based on the `{}` around it is composed of name-value pairs, where name is supposed to be a string.  IMO this nonstandard usage is doomed to cause problems somewhere down the line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to iterate to get the count:

```
 var i=0;
 for (var key in objJSON) i++;
 alert(i);
```

You'd probably want to write a helper for this, something like:

```
function getLength(obj) {
    var i=0;
    for (var key in objJSON) i++;
    return i;
}
alert(getLength(objJSON));
```

To get a key when it isn't a valid Javascript variable name (like numbers, or names that include hyphens, etc), you can use the bracket notation:

```
alert(objJSON[55]);
```

Comment: You're answer really helped but I there's something weird going on I tried this `for (var key in objJSON) {
    alert(key + " : " + objJSON[key]);
}` but its in reverse order.

Comment: @NinjaBoy wow you're right ... that's odd.  Not sure what that's about.  Incidentally, if you're going to be do a lot of object manipulation, it might be worth checking out Underscore.js.  It has utility methods for things like getting all keys or values in an object, sorting, grouping, etc.